# android HttpUrlConnection send post and params get request

Tags: android, httpclient, httpurlconnection

I need a little help with sending an `HttpUrlConnection` from my android application. Till now I was doing this with a basic `Http Client`. But the problem is that when I receive a big stream from the server my applications crash with `outofmemory` exception. And that's why I made a research and find out that `HttpUrlConnection` lets me to get the stream into a pieces. So can anybody help me a little bit with sending my params and getting the response from server?

The previous code that I was using is this :

```
                httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.rpc.your_nightmare.com");

                TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                String deviceId = tm.getDeviceId();
                String resolution = Integer.toString(getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth())+ "x" +
                                             Integer.toString(getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight());
                String version = "Android " + Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
                String locale = getResources().getConfiguration().locale.toString();
                String clientApiVersion = null;

                PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
                PackageInfo packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(this.getPackageName(), 0);
                clientApiVersion = packageInfo.versionName;

                hash = getAuthHash();

                String timestampSQL = "SELECT dbTimestamp FROM users";
                Cursor cursor = systemDbHelper.executeSQLQuery(timestampSQL);
                if(cursor.getCount()==0){
                    Log.i("Cursor","TimeStamp Cursor Empty!");
                } else if(cursor.getCount()>0){
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    timeStamp = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("dbTimestamp"));
                }

                TelephonyManager tMgr =(TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                phoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
                Log.i("Phone","Phone Number : "+phoneNumber);

                postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("debug_data","1"));
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_auth_hash", hash));
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("timestamp", timeStamp));
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobile_phone", phoneNumber));
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("deactivate_collections",Integer.toString(index)));
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_api_ver", clientApiVersion));
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("set_locale", locale));
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("device_os_type", version));
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("device_sync_type", "14"));
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("device_identification_string", version));
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("device_identificator", deviceId));
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("device_resolution", resolution));

                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));

                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                Log.w("Response ","Status line : "+ response.getStatusLine().toString());

                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream stream2 = entity.getContent();


                int nRead;
                byte[] data = new byte[8*1024];

                while ((nRead = stream2.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
                  buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
                }

                buffer.flush();
                return buffer.toByteArray();
```

and than processing it like this :

```
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer, 0, temp.length);
Log.i("Temp","Temp : "+temp.length);
Log.i("index","index : "+index);
responseBody = convertStreamToString(stream);
Log.i("responseBody","responseBody : "+responseBody);
//calculations
```

Comment: I see you are still facing the same problem so I think you are missing some thing which we provide earlier or doing in mistake to use it. So can you provide whole code so we can check it. what are you trying.

Comment: the problem is that the response is too big and i can't convert it to string and parse it. i need to find a way to get it into pieces and as i saw over the android documentation, httpurlconnection is a better way to do this,but it's a little difficult to me to understand how to post the sync params and etc.

Comment: How much response is big? There are many people are using the techniques same as we suggested for response from server.

Comment: Actually it's not the same everytime...At some point I can get only like 1-2MB, at some other situation I can get like 100MB, it depends on what users want.I can show you my whole code if you want

Comment: here is the code if you want to take a look : http://pastebin.com/1DLReRbm

Comment: exactly on which line you got OutOfMemory Error?

Comment: at the beggining - concersation of byte array to string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way you can use `HttpURLConnecion` to make a connection to a web server :

```
        System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(5000); // miliseconds
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Charset", charset);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=" + charset);
        OutputStream output = null;
        try {
            output = connection.getOutputStream();
            output.write(query.getBytes(charset));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (output != null)
                try {
                    output.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

        int status = ((HttpURLConnection) connection).getResponseCode();
        Log.d("", "Status : " + status);

        for (Entry<String, List<String>> header : connection
                .getHeaderFields().entrySet()) {
            Log.d("Headers",
                    "Headers : " + header.getKey() + "="
                            + header.getValue());
        }

        InputStream response = new BufferedInputStream(
                connection.getInputStream());

        int bytesRead = -1;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[30 * 1024];
        while ((bytesRead = response.read(buffer)) > 0 && stopThread) {
            byte[] buffer2 = new byte[bytesRead];
            System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, buffer2, 0, bytesRead);
            // buffer2 is you chunked response
        }
        connection.disconnect();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```