# POST HttpRequest using MultipartEntityBuilder and without deprecated classes

Tags: java, android

I use this method on my code and works fine, but since API22 HttPost, HttpClient, HttpEntity... are deprecated.

I know that the correct update of this code is using HttpURLConnection but I don't know how to use it with my parameters on a MultipartEntityBuilder.

```
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, MultipartEntityBuilder datos) {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();    
      try {
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(datos.build());
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        InputStream is = httpEntity.getContent();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return inputStreamToJSON(is);
}
```

EDIT: So, I changed my code and now the only deprecated class is HttpEntity, I keep searching, this is the updated code:

```
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, MultipartEntityBuilder datos) {
    try {
        HttpEntity entity = datos.build();
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-length", entity.getContentLength() + "");
        conn.setRequestProperty(entity.getContentType().getName(), entity.getContentType().getValue());
        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        entity.writeTo(os);
        os.close();
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return inputStreamToJSON(is);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this [android HttpUrlConnection send post and params get request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818062/android-httpurlconnection-send-post-and-params-get-request)

Comment: There is nothing there that will help the OP. `output.write(query.getBytes(charset));`. What is query?